# where can I find PECL for windows?

Tags: php, pecl

where can I find PECL for windows ?

Comment: No offense, it's a valid PHP question. But seriously, is it that hard to find with Google?

Answer (score 2):

http://downloads.php.net/pierre/

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The pecl4win project has been discontinued. However you can download pretty much every extension as a prebuild .dll from the official [pecl website](http://pecl.php.net/).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes if you can't find the pre-built extension somewhere, you can just Google the name of the dll and find it in someone's directory listing or similar.